# Toggling a class using a variable?

Tags: jquery

Just a quick question, I would like to toggle a class keeping "fontawesome-angle" but toggling 'up' and 'down'? I tried several ways:

```
    $('.build-button').live('click', function(el) {

        var span = $(this).find('span'),
                var icon = //not sure here.. 
                           //I want to toggle between 'up' and 'down'


        span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-'+icon ? 'up' : 'down')

});
```

Sorry this is wrong I know, but I am stumped. This should be quite easy...

Looks like I found a solution:

```
    $('.build-button').live('click', function(el) {
        var span = $(this).find('span'),
            button = $(this),
            icon = $(this).hasClass('function_on')

        button.addClass('function_on')
        $('#content-builder').toggleClass('opened');
        span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-'+icon ? 'up' : 'down')

    });
```

I still need to tweak a few things, but if you want to point anything out go ahead, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: So user clicks "build-button" and that toggles a class on the .toggleClass element? Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: yeah toggling the up and down... I have a beta function above.. I have a few ideas to fix the kinks in the above.. again I am open to other ideas..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry check my answer might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

markup

```
<span class="fontawesome-angle-up">test</span>
<input type="button" value="click" class="build-button"/>
```

js

```
   $(function(){
    $('.build-button').click(function(){
        $('span').toggleClass("fontawesome-angle-up fontawesome-angle-down");
    });
   });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUMED/4/)

Comment: Yeah you got it.. I was curious to learn about `(icon ?'up':'down')` using that kind of syntax.. I knew there was an easier solution, but to me at the time was the cleanest method... I didnt know toggling classes like above switched back and forth between the two.. this is great. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

you could use this two methods :

the default class mb up or down

```
<span class="fontawesome-angle-up" ></span>
```

and you toggling something like this :

```
span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-up');
span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-down');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('.build-button').live('click', function (el) {
     var span = $(this).find('span'),
         button = $(this),
         icon = $(this).hasClass('function_on');

     button.addClass('function_on');
     $('#content-builder').toggleClass('opened');
     span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-up').toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-down');

 });
```

Or

```
span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-'+(icon ?'up':'down'))
```

Comment: Isnt this what I wrote above?

Comment: Oh I see the parentheses, I actually added that, then saw this... it works but there is a slight bug I need to find..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry it took so long.. I forgot jsfiddle and jquery 1.9.1 doesnt allow `.live` lol I sat there trying to debug then looked in the console.. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/CNNVe/2/ its not consistent... even when the class is removed from the get go http://jsfiddle.net/CNNVe/3/ it takes two clicks to change.. Ill think about why its doing that.. prolly something silly

Comment: Here is a much cleaner version if you want http://jsfiddle.net/CNNVe/4/ IMO it has to do with "function_on" its timing is not in sync, prolly not a good approach I am figuring out a work around..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry check demo http://jsfiddle.net/CNNVe/5/ added `fontawesome-angle-up` to span in html and  in js `span.toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-up').toggleClass('fontawesome-angle-down');`

Comment: Yeah this works.. I really wanted to put this syntax to use `(icon ?'up':'down')` so I can learn about it more, but It doesnt apply well here.. the cleanest solution is @Prash `.toggleClass('class1 class2')`